# add border when mouse hovered on MUI v5 table row

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I created a table with Material UI v5 and now when the mouse pointer hovered on the table row I want to add a blue border to the table row.

I have tried a lot of ways and searched but I did not find any solution.

this is what I made so far:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-shirley-s3wii8?file=/demo.tsx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the online example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-faraday-6jb5yt

I did this:

```
const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme }) => ({
  "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover
  },
  "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": {
    border: 0
  },
  '&:hover': {
    border: '3px solid blue'
  },
  [`&.${tableRowClasses.root}`]: {
    borderRadius: "100px"
  }
}));
```

Specifically, including on `StyledTableRow` these lines:

```
  '&:hover': {
    border: '3px solid blue'
  },
```

Comment: thank you, I have 2 more questions: 

1- why (border: '1px solid blue') does not work? because of the default table border?


2- is there any way to add a border radius to the main border? (I mean the table body border)

Comment: About 1: It "works" but it's not visible. Why? because the `th` tag is also showing a border and it overlaps the `tr` border. About 2, you need to Styled the Table component and use the StyledTable instead of Table. And apply the styles to that. You can re-check the codesandbox :) It's updated and included